# Last View In GridView Randomly Not Updating

Tags: android, gridview

This is a very confusing problem since it seems to happen randomly. I have a GridView in which I am setting the size of and number of columns in onCreate(), I'm then populating the grid with randomly selected drawables from an array that are inside imageViews until the gridView is full. When the user clicks on one of these imageViews a background is set on the view to highlight it and when they click another view this highlight is removed. This usually works fine but as the game progresses the grid gets redrawn with more views being added, the problems usually starts on the third redraw of the grid. When the user clicks on the last view inside the gridView it works as it's supposed to but view doesn't update until a second click is made and after the second click the view is one step behind where it should be. I also noticed that if you click inside the gridView and not on any of the views this will also make the last view refresh and go to the state that it should be in.

I believe the problem would be in the imageAdapter so heres the code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return gridSize;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    //loop is an int to show how many views have been drawn
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (loop == 0){  //remove all views before drawing new grid
            grid.removeAllViewsInLayout();
        } 

        if (loop < gridSize+4){stops the code from rerunning once grid drawn
            if (clover == 1){//if power up active
                randomPosition = rng.nextInt(27);
            }

        else if (clover == 0){
            randomPosition = rng.nextInt(12);
        }
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(circleS, circleS));
        imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        imgSet();
        }
        else {
            //do nothing
        }
        return imageView;
    }
    }//end adapter////////
```

I use: if (loop  < gridSize+4) to detect if the grid hasn't already been drawn, this was a workaround because the imageAdapter would re run sometimes when views are clicked, the +4 is because the imageAdapter runs 4 times before adding any views, I have no idea why.

Does any one know of an alternative to this stupid GridView and ImageAdapter?

Comment: you need to post more code. The problem is not likely with GridView, but how you are doing the updates to the grid... and you don't post any code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are updating your dataset `notifyDatasetChanged()`from the main or UI thread, otherwise re-draw is not guaranteed.

It's not a good idea to instantiate objects in the `getView()` method as it gets called many times (`imageView = new ImageView(mContext);`). Take a look at the [ViewHolder pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html), or use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.htmlC).